# Communication with SignalR despite different programming languages?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr, rpc

I have a back-end service written in ASP Net Core 5.0 (C#) and I have a client that is written entirely in JavaScript, but which are completely separate from each other. My question is can I use SignalR for the back-end and open a common connection with my client ?

Although both use different programming languages ?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

Comment: Yes, but there is talk of JS with NodeJS, does it only work in conjunction with NodeJS?

Comment: No, as stated: *The JavaScript client runs on NodeJS 8 and later versions **and** the following browsers*,  you can just use the lib in a simple html page, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: In the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#javascript-client)  it says that you need nodeJS 8+

Comment: Please read: the JavaScript client runs on NodeJS 8 and later versions **and the following browsers**

Comment: Here, see [this sample html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-signalr-client-code). I don't mind answering questions. But please, read some docs, have some faith in the answerer and look around for samples.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your hint, for me it was a bit misleading ;-) I thought you need both NodeJS and one of these browsers :-) Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score -2):

the doc says - The JavaScript client runs on latest version of the browsers.
besides that, has .net and java clients.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.